# Leitura de dados em tempo real

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tentando fazer uma ferramenta para ler e enviar informações(em tempo real) de um log para minha tela.

Até o momento eu consegui ler tudo e enviar as informações linha a linha e enviar as tudo para a tela, segue o código.

```
import time

count = 0
while True:

    arquivo = ('LOG')
    arq = open(arquivo, 'r')
    texto = arq.readlines()
    arq.close()
    count += 1
    print(texto[count])
    time.sleep(5)
```

O problema é que o programa pode ou não, demorar para gerar uma nova linha no log, e quando chega na ultima linha, o problema fecha com o erro.

```
print(texto[count])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Como eu faria para que o programa, aguardando a nova linha ser inserida dentro do arquivo do log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este exemplo pode lhe ajudar. Lê uma linha por vez até o final do arquivo. O método arq.readline() retorna '' enquanto não há linhas novas.
No seu código você estava tentando ler todas as linhas em cada iteração do while.

```
import time


def monitorar(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as arq:
        while True:
            nova_linha = arq.readline()
            nova_linha = nova_linha.replace('\n', '')
            if nova_linha:
                yield nova_linha
            else:
                time.sleep(1.0)

caminho_arquivo = 'teste.log'
for idx, linha in enumerate(monitorar(caminho_arquivo)):
    print("{:5d}: {}".format(idx, linha))
```

Answer (score 0):

Excelente resposta do colega fsola.

Tenho uma sugetão para torna-la mais pythônica. Substituindo o replace pelo strip, reduzimos uma linha de código.

```
#Python3
import time

def monitorar(logfile='file.log'):
    with open(logfile) as file:
        while True:
            linha = file.readline().strip()
            if linha:
                yield linha
            else:
                time.sleep(.5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = 'file.log'
    for item, linha in enumerate(monitorar(logfile)):
        #print(item, linha)
        #print('%s: %s' % (item, linha))
        print('{:6d}: {}'.format(item, linha))
```

Comment: Sendo basicamente a mesma solução, você poderia sugerir a alteração através de um comentário. Quando possuir pontos de reputação suficiente, poderá utilizá-los. Até lá, busque publicar apenas respostas concretas ao problema.